# VirtualBox limits size of .js file, that can be included from shared folder?

Tags: javascript, virtualbox

*This question might belong to SuperUser, but i'll try to ask it here anyway, because i believe, some web developers might encountered this weird behavior.*

---

When testing a site for IE8/winXP compatibility on VirtualBox i run into weird issue of `$ is undefined`, which is caused by jQuery (and jQuery UI) being not included, when referenced by relative path, which resolves to `file:///` url. Seemingly because their size was too big (above 200KB).

Simply replacing links to those 2 big files to `http://` ones solved the issue for me.

But here is the question: **why did this happen ?**

is it a misconfiguration ? a bug ? a known design decision ?

---

Details:

- *VirtualBox 4.1.8*
- *host os: win7 64bit, guest os: xp sp3 32 bit*
- *guest additions installed, page was launched from VB shared folder*
- *the bug was manifesting itself in all browsers (even in opera, which ignores ie security settings, afaik)*
- *ie configuration is default*
- *script was included like this*: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js">`
- *exact size limit was not deducted.*

Comment: It sounds like you're running into the max path length in Windows XP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath. Yes, this is a better question for SU; voted to migrate.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL that was one of the versions ) but no, - i tried renaming jquery file to `j.js` and putting it in same folder with .html file. No effect.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a symlink from your project directory to the vbox shared directory. Oh, this is Windows huh. Blows my mind that people do webdev on windows.

Answer (score 1):

First question: What zone does IE use when loading this HTML file? Look at the bottom-right of the IE window for something like "My Computer" or "Local Intranet". Even though this issue presents itself in other browsers, I am curious to see what IE sees your shared folder as.

This sounds more like a browser issue rather than VirtualBox doing something funny. IE is pretty restrictive about file:// URIs these days as are other browsers to varying degrees...

Do other .js files load OK in the page in question or are they blocked too? What about older versions of jQuery that are much smaller (like v1.3.2)?

Is there some reason you are loading them from a file share rather than from a web server anyway? Do you get the same results if you copy all the files from the shared drive to the guest c:\ drive?

What about upgrading to VirtualBox 4.1.12? I doubt it will make a difference but it might be worth a shot.

The one last thought is that jQuery has some calls which could trigger IE (and possibly others) to block the script - particularly the call the `new ActiveXObject`. Maybe create a small .js file to try to ping that down as the issue. Along those same lines - what happens if you create a garbage, though legitimate .js file that is large - say 400K of something like:

```
var a = "... really, really long string";
var b = "... another really long string";
...
```

Comment: all (30+) other .js files load ok, loading from share means you don't need to upload after saving, and can see your changes faster, upgrading _might_ help, but i'm not currently interested in doing so, because of buzy schedule.